How to wire multiple lights and their respective switches on a single circuit
Somewhat related to this question: Best way to wire multiple lights in multiple rooms on single circuit?, I'm looking for more specific direction as to how I would run a 3 wire circuit, specifically with the addition of fixtures with on-board switches (see "OBS").
My understanding is that I can chain these together using 12-3 and intentionally break the red hot wire when I'm moving on to a new room with a new switch.
Is there anything problematic in my diagram below?
Obviously I've not diagrammed a ground wire. I'm clear on how that would be handled.


Your diagram is correct.  The breaker in the panel can be a 15 or 20 amp.
As you stated, the ground wire must be properly attached in all boxes and fixtures and attached at the panel. (added for others that may not read your entire question.
